# IOS - calling soap webservice with transport based security (HTTPS)

Tags: ios, web-services, soap, https, nsurlconnection

I am developing an IOS application. In which I want to call a soap webservice method(transport based security (HTTPS)). I am following NSURLConnection to call the web service method.
I have used the following code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //Web Service Call
    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"
                             "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope \n"
                             "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \n"
                             "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" \n"
                             "xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
                             "SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
                             "xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> \n"
                             "<SOAP-ENV:Body> \n"
                             "<Service xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                             "</Service> \n"
                             "</SOAP-ENV:Body> \n"
                             "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"];



    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://domain/Service.svc"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];
    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IService/RegisterMethod" forHTTPHeaderField:@"soapAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if(theConnection) {
        webData = [NSMutableData data] ;
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    NSArray *trustedHosts=[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"https://mydomain/"];
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
        if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

But I can't get the response. When I print the "webData", I am getting "<>" empty response.
I am new to the IOS. 
Can anyone tell me, what is the problem in my code (or) I should use any other method to call soap web service with https and give me some useful links.

**Edited:**
I have changed my code as,

```
NSData* bodyData = [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger bodyDataLength = [bodyData length];
[theRequest addValue: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", bodyDataLength] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]
[theRequest setHTTPBody: bodyData]
```

But still I am getting the "webData" value as empty.

Comment: http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/09/invoke-soap-web-service.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks *almost* good ;)

You set the body data as a `NSData` object which you obtain by converting the soap message string into a byte sequence using the character encoding specified in the charset parameter of the Content-Type header (UTF-8).

So far so good. But, the length of the body data is the length of the `NSData` content (in bytes) - not the length of the `NSString` object in UTF-16 code units. ;)

```
NSData* bodyData = [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger bodyDataLength = [bodyData length];
```

Set the Content-Length header accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have changed my code as in edited section in the question. But still I am getting the "webData" value as empty.

Comment: I am passing the method name as [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IService/RegisterMethod" forHTTPHeaderField:@"soapAction"]; is it correct?

Comment: The *request* seems OK for me - technically. However, authentication handling omits trust evaluation - and therefore does not handle server trust verification securely! Also, I can't tell if the "soapAction" is correct (please consult the web service API). Furthermore, I'm assuming you implemented all required delegate methods - e.g. `connection:didReceiveResponse:`, `connection:didReceiveData`, `connection:didFailWithError:`? Please check ALL errors, log error messages, and generously sprinkle your code with assertions.

Comment: I have checked in the didReceiveResponse and I got 415 error code. The problem is "unsupported media type" request. So that I have changed my Content-type to "application/soap+xml". And also I consulted with web service API and I made changes in my request like "SOAP-ENV:" to "s:" (ie)<SOAP-ENV:Envelope> to <s:Envelope>. Now I am getting the correct response. Thanks to CouchDeveloper.

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved the issues :) Now you may want to tackle server trust verification: if the server's certificate is signed by a well known CA, you likely don't need to override authentication delegates: `NSURLConnection`'s default behavior is fine. Otherwise, for self signed certificates, you have to implement corresponding authentication delegates and evaluate the trust manually. You should gather more info about this topic, e.g. from Apple's documentation and SO.